How to format axis values so that the currency sign is aligned in 1 column, no matter how many chars the number has?
My Line Chart
This is how I want it to allign
I have this chart built with Nivo Responsive Line. I have a problem: I want to align currency signs in 1 column, no matter how many characters the number has.
My chart code looks like this:
<ResponsiveLine
        data={data}
        enableArea
        areaBaselineValue={minimalFloored}
        defs={[
          // using plain object
          {
            id: 'gradientC',
            type: 'linearGradient',
            colors: [
              { offset: 0, color: 'inherit' },
              { offset: 100, color: 'inherit' },
            ],
          },
        ]}
        fill={[
          // match using object query
          { match: '*', id: 'gradientC' },
        ]}
        enableCrosshair={true}
        tooltip={(props) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={
                props.point.serieId === DataOrigins.ALIEXPRESS
                  ? `${s.graph__tooltip_red}`
                  : `${s.graph__tooltip}`
              }
            >
              <span className={s.graph__tooltipText}>
                {formatDateToRuLocale(props.point.data.x as Date)}
              </span>
              <span className={s.graph__tooltipText}>
                1$ = {props.point.data.yFormatted}
                {selectedOption.value === SelectValues.BYN ? ' Br' : ' ₽'}
              </span>
            </div>
          );
        }}
        curve="cardinal"
        theme={{
          text: {
            fill: '#747474',
            fontSize: 11,
          },
          legends: {
            text: {
              fontSize: 11,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
            },
          },
        }}
        margin={{ top: 10, right: 60, bottom: 70, left: 60 }}
        xScale={{ type: 'point' }}
        yScale={{
          type: 'linear',
          min: minimalFloored,
          max: 'auto',
        }}
        gridYValues={3}
        gridXValues={20}
        axisTop={null}
        axisRight={{
          tickSize: 0,
          tickPadding: 5,
          tickRotation: 0,
          truncateTickAt: 0,
          format: function noRefCheck(props) {
            return `${props}${
              selectedOption.label === SelectValues.RUB ? ' ₽' : ' Br'
            }`;
          },
        }}
        axisLeft={null}
        axisBottom={{
          tickSize: 0,
          tickPadding: 5,
          tickRotation: -89.97,
          legendOffset: 36,
          legendPosition: 'middle',
          truncateTickAt: 0,
          format: function noRefCheck(props) {
            return formatDateToRuLocale(props);
          },
        }}
        pointSize={3}
        pointColor={{ theme: 'background' }}
        pointBorderWidth={6}
        pointBorderColor={{ from: 'serieColor' }}
        pointLabel="data.yFormatted"
        pointLabelYOffset={-12}
        enableTouchCrosshair={true}
        colors={{
          datum: 'color',
        }}
        useMesh={true}
        legends={[
          {
            anchor: 'bottom',
            translateX: -30,
            translateY: 63,
            direction: 'row',
            justify: false,
            itemsSpacing: 0,
            itemDirection: 'left-to-right',
            itemWidth: 80,
            itemHeight: 20,
            itemOpacity: 0.75,
            symbolSize: 10,
            symbolShape: 'circle',
            symbolBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)',
            effects: [
              {
                on: 'hover',
                style: {
                  itemBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)',
                  itemOpacity: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      />

I format the values in axisRight object in a property "format":
format: function noRefCheck(props) {
            return `${props}${
              selectedOption.label === SelectValues.RUB ? ' ₽' : ' Br'
            }`;
          },

The problem is that this number and the currency is 1 element: <text>104 ₽</text>. I can't add margins. When I try to render an HTML tag, it becomes "[object Object]".
I tried to add more spaces in the strings, but it doesn't allow to have more than 1 space in a string.
